# How to customize UIWebView?

Tags: iphone

Actually i have one table view ,when  Select `rowAtIndexPath` then it load my webView and play my video, how to return from `UIWebView` to my tableView ?

```
 -(void)playButtonPressed1:(UIButton*)sender
 {


 Video *currentVideo= [[xmlParservideo videoNames] objectAtIndex:btn1.tag];


  NSLog(@"content============== %@", [currentVideo content2]);



 CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
 UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
 [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
 NSString *urlString=currentVideo.content2;

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[[self view] addSubview:webView];  
//    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


NSLog(@"jointed2 jjjjjjjjj  %d",btn1.tag);
```

Comment: where you have added your webview in a view or in a view controller or in as same view??

Comment: how do you show your UIWebView?

Comment: Now,I posted all my codes above

Answer (score 1):

Place the Uiwebview in another view controller and push to it when a row is selected and when the video complete pop back to the tableview controller.

Comment: I created  a web view programmatically ,then how to pop back

Answer (score 1):

On didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
videoViewController *newView = [videoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"videoViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

and in your init method of the view controller create the webView programatically

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

    self.title = @"Video Player";
UIWebView  *videoWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 290)];


[videoWebView setDelegate:self];

NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com"; 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];


NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[videoWebView loadRequest:requestObj];


[[self view] addSubview:videoWebView];  


}

return self;
}
```

Ok, Now just pop your view after completing your video

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that may work is using this: `[webView setHidden:YES];`

This hides the webView from the view, so use that line of code whenever you want the webview to disappear. When you want it to return to the view, use this: `[webView setHidden:NO];`